# Do not display Tabel when create new objec as ApplicationDBContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

i create new object as ApplicationDBContext

`ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();`

But when i need to use table for create drowpdowm list , not display to me them .

```
ViewBag.GndId = new SelectList(db.no display table);
```

how can i solve this ?

**Edit :**

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("Model1", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

.

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.GendId = new SelectList(db.)
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @JamesP ViewBag.GndId for create a drowdownlist .

Comment: @JamesP . i need create dynamic drowpdown . i return the tbl_gender from database but it not show me tabels

Comment: And where do you call - `ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();` - sorry, probably best to show whole controller.

Comment: Yes I call That in controller : `namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        `